# Py2Exe + FTDI driver

Tags: python, installation, driver, py2exe, ftdi

Is it at all possible to somehow include the FTDI driver in a py2exe installer? If not, are there any ways to combine the two together in one easy installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the FTDI driver folders in your distribution using py2exe's `data_files` option.

You can run code like this to make the drivers visible to your application even if they aren't installed in system32:

```
os.environ['PATH'] = '%s;%s' % (os.environ['PATH'], os.path.abspath('./driver/i386'))
os.environ['PATH'] = '%s;%s' % (os.environ['PATH'], os.path.abspath('./driver/amd64'))
```

Of course, once a device is plugged in, Windows will ask for a driver.  At least you can point it to where your app is installed to find it.